# How do I create a meteor topic that is for server-only security sensitive information (client cannot subscribe)?

Tags: meteor

The meteor pub/sub mechanism is excellent way to share information across packages on the server without having to share package implementation details with other packages.

I would like to use the publish/subscribe mechanism for security sensitive data. This sensitive topic must only be published and subscribed to by different server components. I.e. clients cannot subscribe to the sensitive topic.

Since the client code can be altered by a malicious user, the server must explicitly prevent a client from successfully subscribing to the sensitive topic.

How can I make a topic private to server(s)?

**Update (for @alanning) :**

*Why I like pub/sub (partial list):*

1. pub/sub is an easy way to reduce the coupling in large projects. packages/modules/whatever don't know who is handling their output or their request (or where) - refactoring is easy because the only entry points are at the topic level, not the code level.
2. pub/sub allows the request to be handled on different VMs without special coding change.
3. pub/sub provides an easy way to route to /dev/null certain kinds of requests when the server is under high load.
4. Easy mock point for testing.
5. Generator of data doesn't need to know how the data is used.
6. 1-N consumers without the producer being aware of the multiple consumers.

*Within Meteor:*

I would like to be able to use the meteor pub/sub mechanism because:

1. Reusing code is awesome
2. meteor pub/sub has the Deps mechanism (awesome^2)
3. meteor pub/sub includes transport mechanism (server to server communication for free?)
4. meteor team is enhancing it - so I don't - hey I am lazy!
5. other servers running other technologies could be shimmed in. ( apache solr, hadoop? )

But sadness:

1. clients are insecure
2. some topics need to be authenticated
3. some topics are internal to server so don't need overhead of packaging data for transport.

Comment: Seems to me that the ideal solution is simply to not have the sensitive items available via the network at all.  IE: have the server keep that stuff to itself, and stuff not on the local machine won't even be able to see it.

Comment: @cHao -- That is exactly the question. The meteor pub/sub mechanism is excellent way to share information across packages on the server without having to share package implementation details with other packages. I don't want these server-only pub/sub topics subscribable by the client.

Comment: Meteor's pub/sub won't work for this use case (see my answer below) but if you provide more info on your goal we may be able to suggest other alternatives.

Comment: The Meteor term for topic here is "publication" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Meteor.subscribe` is only available on the client, not the server.
http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe

**-- Update 2 --**

**Message passing between code within the same process**

Nodejs provides [EventEmitter](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html) which allows setting up custom events.  Import both the 'events' package and the 'util' package to set up inheritance, like so:

`util.inherits(MyQueue, EventEmitter);`

Here's how you would import those npm packages:

- `Npm.require('events')` in a Meteor package
- `Meteor.require('events')` in a Meteor application using the [`npm` meteorite package](http://meteorhacks.com/complete-npm-integration-for-meteor.html)

Here is an [example](https://gist.github.com/jedp/1894029) of using it to listen to a redis queue.  Setting up your own queue is primarily a matter of convention as to what events to publish and listen to.

**-- Update 1 --**

**Message passing between code running in different processes**

A pub/sub queue is definitely a great choice and you have several ways to implement that.  Here are two that come to mind:

- implement a poor-man's queue using Mongo collections
- use a 3rd-party message queue such as RabbitMQ

***Mongo Collections***

Doing it with Mongo is possible depending on your requirements.  A quick search brings up several implementations and design discussions (mostly Ruby): https://www.google.com/search?q=pubsub+queue+with+mongo . Careful, with this though...in the long run this could end up being more work.  Depends on what features you need.

***A 3rd-party message queue***

An actual queue solution provides the best means to enable distributed messaging.  You can set up a RabbitMQ cluster which your Meteor processes interact with to distribute work.  Provides nice benefits such as high availability and guaranteed delivery.  Also, workers don't have to be nodejs processes; any AMPQ client could receive tasks.

Comment: Really? sadness here.

Comment: Thanks for the update.  I've edited my answer to suggest alternatives.

Comment: did not know about rabbitMQ. will keep that bookmarked for later reference. At this point, the messaging is just between meteor packages in the same VM. In the future, we will need something like RabbitMQ. Currently my goal is getting the program built with messaging built in (to avoid wholesale reworking later). What about intra meteor messaging within the same VM between different packages?

Comment: Updated with suggestion for in-process messaging.

Answer (score 1):

I use the Accounts system to do this. On the server I create an admin account and add an `admin : true` property to it (outside of the profile so it's not user-changeable).

My `Meteor.publish` code checks `this.userId`, does an `Meteor.users` lookup on this id and ensures there is an `admin : true` property. If it doesn't find this property, it returns an empty cursor.

While it is technically possible for a client to subscribe, only by managing to get the username/password of an admin account. The benefit is there's no hacky code involved.

Comment: You can also use a package like: https://github.com/deepwell/meteor-authorization or https://github.com/alanning/meteor-roles