# MeteorJS App Security

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I was a bit curious for feedback on security of the following structure:

Meteor server side app (using Mongo of course)
Meteor Mobile App, I understand this has a mini-Mongo

From the tutorials I read, the local mini-Mongo saves data needed for the mobile app, while calls to sync with the parent mongo on the server happens when there is a network connection.

Is it my responsibility on a code level to restrict what gets saved in client mini-Mongo? Examples:

- A team admin can add/edit/create users. Would that mean it syncs with his device going forward? If the user changes his password would it sync to device of the team admin? I know its hashed, but thats not the point
- The pub/sub would let me limit other pages to my data, or my team data so that seems to help
- Is it safe to assume if I don't pub/sub the data would not be saved in the mini-Mongo on the client?

This might have the answer: [How do I create a meteor topic that is for server-only security sensitive information (client cannot subscribe)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852623/how-do-i-create-a-meteor-topic-that-is-for-server-only-security-sensitive-inform)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MiniMongo basically stores data it gets from certain **messages over [DDP](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/ddp/DDP.md)** (Meteor's data protocol). Normally, the data is not cached locally and is re-created each time the page reloads, assuming we're talking about a hybrid mobile app that's rendered in a WebView.

You can take a look at the messages passed using [Meteor DevTools for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/meteor-devtools/ippapidnnboiophakmmhkdlchoccbgje?hl=en).

Those messages (`added`/`changed`/`removed`) are normally sent via the **pub/sub** system. It is indeed **you responsibility to decide** what gets sent. You have complete control over modeling roles and permissions in your system, and over who gets what in your publication, since a publication is initiated by a function call on the server.

A common pattern for this is:

```
Meteor.publish('someProtectedPblication', function(/*...*/) {
  if (this.userId && someCondition(this.userId) { // check for permission
    return SomeCollection.find(someData, someFields); // return a cursor that gets synced with the user
  }
  return this.ready(); // the user is not authorized to view the data
});
```

When an **admin creates a user**, I assume this is done via a Meteor method call, i.e, an **RPC**. There is no reason for that user's data (not to mention their hashed password) to be available to the admin on the client side, or stored in his cached database collection, unless you explicitly publish it to him (which I don't see a reason to do, ever).

I don't find much value in using client-side MiniMongo mutations (`insert`/`update`/`delete`) on the client side, except for optimistic UI rendering, as I view securing this using `allow/deny` rules less secure and more error prone, and I use Meteor methods for any mutation.

Comment: Amazing answer, thanks. Do you mind another question, testing the first feature, running meteor debug ios, it gets a 500 on the ws server. 

I am just using some test code from a tutorial for that, so it could be its not configured right, I'll delve into it a bit more

Comment: I have not tried using Meteor cordova on iOS, so I don't really know much about it. Anyway, `meteor debug` is now deprecated.